# Is this a question with answers or should I look elsewhere

Tags: discussion, questions

My employer has instituted a policy whereby access to github is blocked at the network level.  So if you attempt to go there using http/s its blocked, regardless of what you are accessing.  This was done as a result of unauthorised sharing of code.

Now there is a process of getting exceptions to this policy by completing a form.  I am wondering why you would say its essential to have github access even without using it as a repo.  We do use 3rd party components hosted on github.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question would not be permitted. It would likely be closed as off-topic as it relates to your career and workplace or as opinion-based as we cannot tell you why you need access to GitHub in order to do your job. You know what your work is and should be able to provide a justification for why you need an exception to the block.